# Apple watch using background refresh

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

Since apple watch is just an interface. Can I use background refresh to update the apple watch screen while the app is in the background mode not in foreground?

And if yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the screen when for some reason a page deactivates, like for example, switching to another page. You should be using the method:

```
- (void)didDeactivate {
// This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
[super didDeactivate];
}
```

Which is on every WKInterfaceController class.